# How can we make equal space between all ticks with unequal values for an linearscale in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I was looking for getting an equal space between each ticks.

How can we get the equal space between each ticks with unequal intervals using scale linear.

How can we get the equal space between each ticks with unequal intervals using scale linear.

How can we get the equal space between each ticks with unequal intervals using scale linear.

I'm using d3 verison 4.
Below is the snippet.

```js
var xCoordinates = [20, 25, 31.5, 40, 50, 63, 80,
  100, 125, 160, 200, 250, 315,
  400, 500, 630, 800, 1000, 1200,
  1600, 2000, 2500, 3200, 4000, 5000,
  6300, 8000, 10000, 12500, 16000, 20000];

var yCoordinates = [-18, -15, -12, -9, -6, -3, 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18];

var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50};
  var width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right;
  var height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

console.log(d3);

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain(d3.extent(xCoordinates))
   .rangeRound([0,width]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
   .domain(d3.extent(yCoordinates))
   .range([height, 0]);

var svg = d3.select('.graph').append('svg')
   .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
   .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
   .append('g')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

  var xAxis = svg.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'x-axis')
   .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
   .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
    .ticks(10)
    .tickValues(xCoordinates)
    .tickPadding(5)
    .tickFormat(function(d){
     if(d===20){
      d = d+'Hz';
     }
     else if ((d / 1000) >= 1) {
      d = d / 1000 + "k";
     }
     return d;
    }));

  var yAxis = svg.append('g')
   .attr('class', 'y-axis')
   .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)
    .tickValues(yCoordinates)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
     if(d===0){
      d = d+'dB';
     }
     return d;
    }));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.js"></script>
<div class="graph"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is only going to have X values that match the values in xCoordinates then you could use scaleOrdinal.

However, if your data will have X values that will fall between the values in xCoordinates, and you want the xScale to position the data points linearly between the points on the X axis, you would have to:

- set the array for xScale.range to have the same number of values as xCoordinates array and
- each item in the  xScale.range array would be a set interval between 0 and width. For example your xCoordinates 31 items, so each values in the xScale.range array would be [(0 * (width/31)), (1 * (width/31)), (2 * (width/31)), ...(30 * (width/31))].  Which you could create with for loop or similar

Comment: That's good - Which option were you after (scaleOrdinal, or using multiple values in the .range)?

Comment: Using multiple values in range