Recharts evenly space xAxis ticks
Hi guys as you can se here : SandBox, I am trying to have certain ticks lets say [100,200, 10000,30000, 250000] and i want to display them all but when i display them all the one that have small gap overlap. What i want somehow is to have even spaces between all the ticks no matter of the difference in value between them.
I tried to put some scale with scaleSymlog but that doesnt seem to work as expected

using a symlog scale works as expected sandbox. There is no scale type on a number axis that will always get you even distribution no matter the distance if you specify your own ticks. You could change your axis to categorical, but then you won't be able to interpolate ticks at numerical positions.

than what is my option?

number scales do not work like you want them to (in recharts or d3 and just in general). So your options are either not have your ticks distributed evenly, or to use a categorical axis. In that case though the tick value must exist in your data set. You can also try to create your own scale and pass it to recharts, but it would be custom similar to the answer given here to do this in d3 https://stackoverflow.com/a/45177900/8050147
